# rotation scrollview paging in ios

Tags: paging, scrollview

I made scrollview page.

and swipe gesture

in scrollview. 1page->2page->3page->4page

but 4page->1page is not impossible.

I would like to make a rotation scrollview.

how I implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different ways to do this, and it really depends on what you're using the ScrollView for and how many pages you need to page through.  [Here](http://zdima.net/blog/archives/15533) they describe two such strategies with well-commented code so you can understand what each line of the code does.